# Uninitialized Keystore : even after loading

Tags: java-7, keystore, java-6, jks

I have Java 1.7 with Eclipse Luna application where I try to get the aliases of the Java keystore after loading it.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray());
    //Print aliases below  
    Enumeration<String> aliases=null;
    try 
    {
    aliases = ks.aliases();
    } 
    catch (KeyStoreException e)
    {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (aliases.hasMoreElements()) 
    {
    String alias = aliases.nextElement();
    System.out.println("Alias is: "+alias);
    }
```

I was able to get this working in Eclipse Indigo in Java 1.6  but the same code in Java 1.7 with Eclipse Luno gives me this error:

```
     java.security.KeyStoreException: Uninitialized keystore
    at java.security.KeyStore.aliases(KeyStore.java:1002)
    at sun.security.ssl.SunX509KeyManagerImpl.<init>(SunX509KeyManagerImpl.java:125)
    at sun.security.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509.engineInit(KeyManagerFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory.init(KeyManagerFactory.java:259)
```

I see the `aliases` being set to `null` when using 1.7. Not sure if this is dependent on the environments but that is what I was able to figure out so far. I will need to make it work with Java 1.7 as I need to use TLSV1.2 which Java 6 doesn't support.
Any thoughts?

Comment: I am also learning that TLS1.2 is now compatible with Java 6u121 version as well. So I am trying that option as well but Any thoughts on why the Java 7 version is not loading the KeyStore?

Comment: I am having the same issue with a p12 BouncyCastle truststore.  How did you resolve this?

Comment: @dev4life Its been a while but I think I used this java version jdk7u121